# Why 'gcov' data isn't generated when running program with 'expect'?

Tags: c++, expect, gcov

Suppose a source file called `xmpl.cpp` ([the one described by Fröhlich](http://gaming.jhu.edu/~phf/tut/gcov-tutorial.pdf), for instance). When compiling this file with `gcc` with the flags `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage`, it generates in the usual binary executable file `xmpl` and a gcov data file `xmpl.gcno`. Then, when the program is executed another gcov data file `xmpl.gcna` is generated, this one containing information gathered during the execution.

However, when I use an expect script to run that same program no `xmpl.gcna` is generated. More specifically, the problem is with the `spawn` command, with `exec` everything is fine (but then, why use expect, right?).

I'm interested in solving this issue because we have lots of expect scripts performing some tests in our project and currently no coverage information is being generated for those tests. The code for the example described above can be fetched [here](https://github.com/freitass/gcov-expect-example).

Answer (score 1):

Both `spawn` and `exec` create a new process to execute the program. [The difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554304/what-is-the-difference-between-spawn-and-exec) is that `exec` suspends the execution of TCL (Expect) until the execution completes. Since the program never reaches it's "natural end" when running the program with `spawn`, no coverage information get to be generated.

To fix the problem, one have to wait until the subprocess finishes before letting the expect script to end its execution, which can be achieved by expecting an `eof`. This is what the expect script should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./xmpl Hey! xxx

expect eof
```